# Expand Detailed View in Kendo Grid without selecting the row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid within grid, a detailed view, and I want to be able to expand a row without selecting it.  Every time I press the image on the far left of the row in the parent grid, the button that expands the row, it selects that row as well.

**Is there a way to click the "expander" without selecting the row in the parent grid?**

Thank you guys.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeModel>()
      .Name("SomeGrid")
      .Columns(c =>
          {
              // some columns (abbreviated)
          })
      .Selectable(s => s.Enabled(true).Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
      .ClientDetailTemplateId("someTemp")
      .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound").Change("onSomeGridChange"))
      .DataSource(d => d.Ajax().Model(model => model.Id(p => p.SomeId)))
      )  

<script id="someTemp" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeObject>()
      .Name("grid_#=SomeId#")
      .Columns(c =>
          {
              // some columns (abbreviated)
          })
      .Selectable(s => s.Enabled(true).Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
      .Events(events => events.Change("onOther GridChange"))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetSomeData", "Controller", new { blNumber = "#=SomeId#" })))
      .ToClientTemplate()
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, its all happening because of `.Selectable(s => s.Enabled(true).Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))`. If you strictly need this option, you can wire up [detailExpand](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-detailExpand) event on master gird and [clear](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-clearSelection) the row/sell selections.

```
<script>
    function onDetailExpand(e) {
        e.sender.clearSelection();
    }
</script>
```